# Alright here is a challenge for the super users

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I did a data import and one column the first name came in as duplicates and I have no delimiter to spit by. Question is how to split the text at the second capital letter?

IE A1

```
DanDan
DonalDonald
JackJack
ChrisChris
```

want A1 to be just Dan

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting at the second capital letter, split at the half of the text:

```
=MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to do that directly with a normal Excel function; it will require the use of VBA.

[This page](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/369471-how-split-camelcase-text-cells.html) has a couple of examples of how you might do this.  The shorter of the two code samples is like this:

```
Sub CamelCase()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCount As Long

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "([a-z])([A-Z])"
        .Global = True
        For Each rCell In Selection
            lCount = .Execute(rCell).Count
            If lCount Then rCell.Resize(, lCount + 1) = Split(.Replace(rCell, "$1" & Chr(1) & "$2"), Chr(1))
        Next rCell
    End With
End Sub
```

This will take any cell that contains mixed case words (`AppleBabyCat`) and split them at each new uppercase letter into their own cells (`Apple` `Baby` `Cat`).

Answer (score 0):

This formula will work:

```
=LEFT(A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & LEN(A1)))/(EXACT(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & LEN(A1))),1),UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & LEN(A1))),1)))),1)-1)
```

This assumes that the first capital is the first character and the second is after that.

It iterates through the letters starting from the 2nd to the end and finds where the letter is exactly equal to the capital version of that letter.

It then returns the first location of that letter to the Left Function.

[image]